# How was this full URL found?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dopostback

A co-worker took this url: https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/BS_PressReleaseDisplay.aspx which has month/year pagination via Javascript (see the elements on the right) and was able to give me this url:

https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/BS_PressReleaseDisplay.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMTg0MTg0MzQ2NmRk1lDKkbV9IbwhES0FyX%2BlSLhp%2FzA%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=380F4D6F&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAiUUGGuo52vbcR6TOSGc2%2FnlK%2BXrsQEVyjeDxQ0A4GYXFBwzdjZXczwplb2HKGyLlqLrBfuDtX7nV3nL%2B5njT0xZDpy7WJnvc3tgXY08CYLJD%2BrfdwJAuBoVBISURIXWlx9xf1loRXvygROM%2FA1O%2BNHJounKCGGAHd04zzVhBPZz4BK5Wx46wqhV0iQkxGw1Nhr9A6c&hdnYear=2016&hdnMonth=12&UsrFontCntr%24txtSearch=&UsrFontCntr%24btn=

where I can replace the year after hdnYear and the month after hdnMonth with any year and month, and it will bring me directly to that page.  I asked him how he did it, and he said "I used the Network tab in Chrome dev tools."  That's about all I could get out of him.

Does anyone know exactly how this is done?  For example, I'm now trying to discover similar way to get the actual url for each page of this site: http://www.ojk.go.id/id/regulasi/otoritas-jasa-keuangan/peraturan-dan-keputusan-dewan-komisioner/Default.aspx  by looking at the Network tab as I change pages.  There is nothing I can see in there that's similar to the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it was done for the `rbi.org.in` URL you've mentioned

1. Open `Chrome` and go to the [URL](https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/BS_PressReleaseDisplay.aspx) you've given
2. Right click on the page and select `Inspect`
3. Click on the `Network` tab.
4. Click on one of the year/month links on the website (the pagination you referred to)
5. In the `Network` tab, you'll see a list of `GET/POST` requests being made by the client (ie, the browser) to the server.
6. In the `Filter` box (on the top-left of the `Network` tab), type in the search filter `method:POST`.
7. Click on the entry in the `Name` column. This will open up more details about the `POST` request. Scroll down to the section titled `Form Data`.
8. Click on the `view encoded` button in the `Form Data` section
9. These are the parameters your friend included in the URL. You'll notice `hdnYear` and `hdnMonth` also listed in there. The URL your friend gave can be obtained by clicking on `view source`

Comment: This is such great information that will save me a lot of time. I did try and parse out the ojk.go.id site using this method and the resulting url is LONG, and actually only works for a short time.  Is this because the site owner is trying to avoid automatic scapers/spiders/bots?

Answer (score 1):

Well I can't really tell you how to exactly reproduce this in the site you're trying to, but I can tell you what your co-worker did.

In the page https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/BS_PressReleaseDisplay.aspx:

- Open the network tab in dev tools, clean the log if theres anything there.
- Click on a year and month
- On the network log search for BS_PressReleaseDisplay.aspx in the "Name" column and click on it
- Inside the Headers tab go to "Form Data" and click on "view source"

And thats it, theres is the URL parameters that your coworker gave you, you can try doing this on the site you want to reproduce it clicking on another page and searching for Default.aspx, but you'll have to figure out what does each parameter means to find which one is the page number or whatever you're looking for (check it in the parsed view for easier reading).

Screenshots: 
http://prnt.sc/emsl2w
http://prnt.sc/emsm2z

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The URL he sent you, has URL parameters/query-strings that, is read by the server which then sends you the selected pages.

So basically the servers pics up the request and reads these paramters which then most likely is parsed into a method of some sort, querying a database then returning the result for you.

If your the owner of the linked website, you can implement such solution, otherwise you´re stuck since it requires coding on the backend.

Comment: This actually explains URL parameters pretty well: http://www.getsymphony.com/learn/concepts/view/url-parameters/